Producing messages from Clickhouse materialized view to Kafka topic by Kafka Engine writes messages with key=null
I am using Kafka Engine for sink data from ClickHouse to Kafka topic. It sends records to Kafka with key=null.
How to define key for KafkaRecord with Kafka table engine ?
I created next materialized view :
> CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW  myView on cluster '{cluster}'
>         ENGINE =  Kafka('kafka:9092', 'MyTopic', 'MyConsumerGroup',
>                         'JSONEachRow')
> 
>             SETTINGS  kafka_thread_per_consumer = 0, kafka_num_consumers = 2
>         POPULATE AS select toYYYYMMDD(source_day) as _key,  lastUpdateTime, groupId, source_day, sourceId,
>          languages from MyTable FORMAT JSONEachRow;

I see messages in Kafka:
Key=null,
Value={
"_key": "20231020"
"lastUpdateTime": "2020-01-23 17:42:40",
"groupI": "546-967",
"source_day": "2023-10-20",
"sourceId": "158753",
"languages": [
[
"en",
1
]
]
}
I am expecting Key="20231020", Value={
"lastUpdateTime": "2020-01-23 17:42:40",
"groupI": "546-967",
"source_day": "2023-10-20",
"sourceId": "158753",
"languages": [
[
"en",
1
]
]
}

I have find the issue.
Field _key must be of String type.
toString(source_day) as _key

fixed my issue
